# In the youngtab package, how can I achieve a skew hook tableau, without the content?

Tags: packages

I have `\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab}` in my preamble. And I can write something like `\young(abcd,:cd,:c)` which gives the output
 [image]

The problem is that I need to create a version of that in which the cells are empty. Empty cells in traditional tableaux are easy enough using `\yng ...` and so I guess my question is how can I skew them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. | no tested solution: have you tried `\young(a{}cd,:cd,:c)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[enableskew]{youngtab} 
\begin{document}
$\young(~~~~,:~~,:~)$
\end{document}
```

[image]